# Starting a Gui application from within SBT (OSX)

Tags: swt, sbt, jface

I am trying to start a jface/swt application (I know oldschool but legacy demand),from within SBT. jface/swt application requires the option "-XstartOnFirstThread"

I have tried to add

```
javaOptions := Seq("-XstartOnFirstThread", "-d64"),
fork in run := true
```

But it does not work. Any idea how i can do that? or even if it possible?

Comment: What's oldschool about SWT/JFace? :D

Answer (score 0):

Setting `javaOptions in run` should help, as [documented](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Forking.html#Forked+JVM+options) in the reference manual.

#### build.sbt

```
javaOptions in run := Seq("-XstartOnFirstThread", "-d64")

fork in run := true
```